# I have a Linux VHD with multiple partitions on it. How do I mount them ALL and migrate to Hyper-V?

Tags: linux, azure, vhd

I have a Linux-VHD that I pulled from from Azure. The VHD has partitions for os, sdc1, sdd1 and sde1 (4 Part). The files I want to recover are on one main partition for Hyper-V. How do I mount and boot them on hyper-V?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to just create a VM and set your VHD as the HDD source. If this is not the case, can you provide any errors in regards to attempting to connect the drive to a Hyper-v VM?

Comment: i have 4 HDDs. Where should i set those VDs in stroge part? as IDE, SATA, SCSI or SAS?

when they are so located;

IDE Primary Master : OS.vhd SATA Port 0 : sdc1.vhd SATA Port 1 : sdd1.vhd SATA Port 2 : sde1.vhd

linux Suse Ent.11 doesnt started! i got a boot screen "Gnu Grub version 0.97" after that when i choose "SLES-11-SP3",i got black screen.